# OR Statement not working even when conditions are met?

Tags: excel, vba

**Overview**

I am currently working on a simple function to help validate the starting place of my array. I am using a DO statement and then just offsetting the active cell until the conditions of my DO Statement are met.

**Code**

```
Public Function ArrayStart() As Variant

    Range("A3").Select


    Do


        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select


    Loop While (ActiveCell.Value <> "Date" Or _
                ActiveCell.Value <> "Open" Or _
                ActiveCell.Value <> "High" Or _
                ActiveCell.Value <> "Low" Or _
                ActiveCell.Value <> "Close" Or _
                ActiveCell.Value <> "Adj Close" Or _
                ActiveCell.Value <> "Volume")

    ArrayStart = ActiveCell.Row


End Function
```

**Data in the Excel Sheet**

```
Date        Open    High     Low    Close   Adj Close  Volume
12/22/1998  19.05   19.05   18.85   18.94     9.98     55900
12/23/1998  18.86   19.22   18.86   19.22     10.13    78800
12/24/1998  19.22   19.34   19.15   19.34     10.20    43800
12/28/1998  19.33   19.33   19.04   19.09     10.06    51900
12/29/1998  19.12   19.29   18.89   19.29     10.17    100800
12/30/1998  19.19   19.32   19.09   19.22     10.13    154600
12/31/1998  19.22   19.24   19.04   19.04     10.04    65400
```

The Date is located in Range "A4"  and the entire range of all the data is located in range "A4:G11"

**Problem**

The code works until it gets to the Loop While section and even though the activecell is "A4" which is the "Date" it will not recognize it as such, and will continue to keep looping.

When I take the OR conditions out and use this code it works perfect

```
Loop While (ActiveCell.Value <> "Date")
```

I am running the same overall code but eliminating the OR statement and it works great, I am getting no errors and I just cant understand why it is not working. Also when I hover my mouse over the activecell.value in the vba window it shows "Date" when it gets to cell "A4" ???

Comment: Consider a simpler statement - `x <> "A" Or x <> "B"`.  If x is `"A"` then it isn't `"B"` so the statement becomes `False Or True` which is `True`. If x is `"B"` then it isn't `"A"` so the statement becomes `True Or False` which is `True`.  If x is `"C"` then it isn't `"A"` or `"B"` so the statement becomes `True Or True` which is `True`.  In other words, it is **always** `True`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
Public Function ArrayStart() As Variant
    Range("A1").Select
    Do
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    Loop Until (ActiveCell.Value = "Date" Or _
                ActiveCell.Value = "Open" Or _
                ActiveCell.Value = "High" Or _
                ActiveCell.Value = "Low" Or _
                ActiveCell.Value = "Close" Or _
                ActiveCell.Value = "Adj Close" Or _
                ActiveCell.Value = "Volume")
    ArrayStart = ActiveCell.Row
End Function
```

Avoid using `ActiveCell`, see [this](http://dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2004/04/27/beginning-vba-select-and-activate/) for details. More efficient code will be

```
Public Function ArrayStartMMM() As Variant
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Range("A1")
    Do
        Set rng = rng.Offset(1, 0)
    Loop Until (rng.Value = "Date" Or _
                rng.Value = "Open" Or _
                rng.Value = "High" Or _
                rng.Value = "Low" Or _
                rng.Value = "Close" Or _
                rng.Value = "Adj Close" Or _
                rng.Value = "Volume")
    ArrayStart = rng.Row
End Function
```

Comment: What is the difference between Loop While and Unitl? The Loop while will work when I take the OR condition out

Comment: @ZacAttack - `DO-WHILE` loop iterates as long as a certain condition is true where as `DO-UNTIL` iterates until a condition is no longer true.